# I want to add server ip address in Azure Application gateway backend address pool

Tags: networking, powershell

i tried to add Public ip of my server to application gateway backend address pool when i execute the command in powershell it runs and shows no response and no addition shows up in azure portal.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the backend ip's to the right gateway? first line of code refers to the "WAF-Staging", second one to the"WAF-Staging_BE". I also noticed you're filling the `$WAF` variable with your changes, do you actually run it afterwards?

Comment: Actually the WAF-STAGING is Gateway name & waf-Staging_BE is Backend Pool name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to add the Public IP of Virtual Machine or LoadBalancer to Application Gateway.

```
Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name "Gateway name" -ResourceGroupName "Resource Group" | Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -Name "Backend Pool name" -BackendIPAddresses "Public IP" | Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway
```